# How can I set -webkit-text-fill-color in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, webkit

On my website, I have two `a` links and I am using javascript to set the `href` attributes of them. If there is no link, then I change the color to black. However, in Safari on iPhone, to get the color to work right, I have to use `-webkit-text-fill-color`. So now I need to change the `webkit-text-fill-color` property using javascript. I tried `element.style.-webkit-text-fill-color = "color"` but I get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'`. Any idea if you can change it with javascript and if so, whats the syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `element.style.webkitTextFillColor = "color"`

Comment: For react, the first "W" should be uppercase.